# Is there any finger print reader api in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, fingerprint, windows-10-mobile

I want to read the user's finger print through my windows phone application. Is there any api to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The upcoming windows anniversary sdk (now in preview) will bring expose some of the window hello biometric authenication classes.

http://mspoweruser.com/windows-10-anniversary-sdk-bring-new-opportunities-developers/

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-developer-preview